# Get camera stream on own web page with basic authentication

Tags: jquery, html, camera

I want to embed a camera stream on my own webpage.

When I go to this url I see the stream:

```
http://user:pwd@ip/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=full&html
```

This is part of the returned html:

```
<img src="/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?">
```

Embedding the image like this on my own page doesn't work because I get a 401 error

```
<img src="http://user:pwd@ip/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?">
```

I tried a GET with jquery but then I get a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://ip/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?",
    type: 'GET',
    username: "user",
    password: "pwd",
    success: function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Any idea/tips how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this the uggly way, but it works.

In an invisible iframe I load an url just to get the basic authentication.
After the iframe is loaded I set the src of the image stream.

```
$("#authframe").load(function () {
    $('img').attr('src', "http://ip/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg");
});
```